# Is it possible to use explicit binding for an interface where a Ninject convention binding already exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, binding, ninject

I am getting a NinjectActivationException when binding one of my interfaces to a class

> Error activating IInitialUploadFolderCleaner More than one matching
>   bindings are available. Matching bindings: 1) binding from
>   IInitialUploadFolderCleaner to InitialUploadFolderCleaner 2) binding
>   from IInitialUploadFolderCleaner to InitialUploadFolderCleaner
>   Activation path: 1) Request for IInitialUploadFolderCleaner
>   Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   IInitialUploadFolderCleaner only once.

So, I am using a convention binding with `BindDefaultInterface()` method, however for this class I want to add a constructor argument - a string. 
In order to achieve that, I wanted to specify the explicit binding, hoping that ninject would only use default binding when no explicit binding was found.

```
  kernel.Bind<IInitialUploadFolderCleaner>().To<InitialUploadFolderCleaner>().WithConstructorArgument("siteRootPath", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath);


        kernel.Bind(x =>
        {
            x.FromAssembliesMatching("MyPrefix.*")
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .BindDefaultInterface();
        });
```

However, it turns out that it doesn't work this way, or it requires some extra setting. 
I am not binding this interface explicitly anywhere else, and also when I rename the implementation so that it does not follow the naming convention, then it works fine and I get all constructor arguments OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to exclude particular types in convention-based binding, so that you can still write explicit binding for them.

```
   kernel.Bind<IInitialUploadFolderCleaner>().To<InitialUploadFolderCleaner>().WithConstructorArgument("siteRootPath", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath); 

   kernel.Bind(x =>
    {
        x.FromAssembliesMatching("MyPrefix.*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .Excluding<InitialUploadFolderCleaner>()
            .BindDefaultInterface();
    });
```